# Make visible, which Accordion Tab is opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this "Accordion Type" Snippet right now. It opens the content below the button on click and closes it again. Now I am looking for a solution to make the state of the button visible to the user e.g if Button 2 is opened, I want to show a "-" indicating that it can be closed with a click. Same with the closed buttons to show a "+". Is this possible? Thanks in advance :)

This is my code right now:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.ss_button').on('click', function() {
jQuery('.ss_content').not(jQuery(this).next('.ss_content')).slideUp('fast');
jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideToggle('fast');
  });
  jQuery('.ss_content').eq(1).show();
});
```

```css
#ss_menu {
  width: auto;
}

.ss_button {
  background-color: #049132;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ss_content {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss_menu">
  <div class="ss_button">Einsteiger</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button">Mittelklasse</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button">High-End</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some changes to your css:

```
.ss_button:before {
  content: "+ ";
}

.ss_button.active:before{
content: "- ";
}
```

Then we toogle the `active` class:

```
jQuery('.ss_button.active').not(jQuery(this)).removeClass('active')
jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
```

This way you don't have to change your html.

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.ss_button').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ss_button.active').not(jQuery(this)).removeClass('active')
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
    jQuery('.ss_content').not(jQuery(this).next('.ss_content')).slideUp('fast');
    jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideToggle('fast');
  });
  jQuery('.ss_content').eq(1).show();
});
```

```css
#ss_menu {
  width: auto;
}

.ss_button {
  background-color: #049132;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ss_button:before {
  content: "+ ";
}

.ss_button.active:before{
content: "- ";
}

.ss_content {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss_menu">
  <div class="ss_button">Einsteiger</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button active">Mittelklasse</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button">High-End</div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @JonasLinde No problem, happy to help.

Comment: I dont know if you can help me with this one, or if I should open a new thread, but how can I make the Page scroll to the Button on click? (The buttons will be used on mobile only and have pretty long content.) Right now the beginning of the content is not visible on the top of the page. I hope the question is not confusing, dont know how to phrase it differently :D

Comment: @JonasLinde I would suggest that you open a new thread, that way questions dont get mixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty span in your buttons and change the content (+ or -) in the click functions.
Check lines #4 and #6, the same of the code is the same.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.ss_button').on('click', function() {
    jQuery('.ss_content').not(jQuery(this).next('.ss_content')).slideUp('fast');
    jQuery('.ss_button').find('span').text('+');
    jQuery(this).next('.ss_content').slideToggle('fast');
    jQuery(this).find('span').text('-');
  });
  jQuery('.ss_content').eq(1).show();
});
```

```css
#ss_menu {
  width: auto;
}

.ss_button {
  background-color: #049132;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ss_content {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss_menu">
  <div class="ss_button">Einsteiger 
    <span>+</span></div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button">Mittelklasse
    <span>+</span></div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ss_button">High-End
    <span>+</span></div>
  <div class="ss_content">
    <p>Test3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```